# Как сменить изображение с помощью кнопки на jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть две кнопки, и к ним нужно привязать функцию смены картинки по нажатию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтоб я не пробовал у меня не получается сделать так, чтоб переключался продукт, последнее, что я попробовал:

```
 $(function() {
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
     $('#img').attr('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg');
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

В метод [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) первым параметром передаётся **название атрибута**, а вторым его **значение**.

В случае для изменении изображения, требуется указать в название - `.attr('src', 'ссылка на картинку');`:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#img').attr('src', 'img2.jpg'); // or img1.jpg
});
```

Answer (score 0):

На Javascrip переключать картинки можно вот так, лёгким нажатием кнопки:

```js
const img = document.getElementById("img");
const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

btn1.disabled = true;

btn1.addEventListener('click', e => {
  img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Postgresql_elephant.svg";
  btn1.disabled = true;
  btn2.disabled = false;
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', e => {
  img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/ISO_C%2B%2B_Logo.svg/306px-ISO_C%2B%2B_Logo.svg.png?20170928190710";
  btn1.disabled = false;
  btn2.disabled = true;
});
```

```css
.container>img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container"><img id="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Postgresql_elephant.svg" alt="postgresql"></div>
<div><button id="btn1"><<</button><button id="btn2">>></button></div>
```